# Building libvorbis from source using Mingw: "You must have automake installed to compile vorbis"

Tags: windows, mingw, automake, vorbis

I am trying to port a project I made on gnu/linux to windows. The project uses the vorbis library to decode ".ogg" files.

I need to build the project from source as I could not find any pre-built binaries for windows. On linux I just installed the "libvorbis-dev" package.

The README tells me that I should type `./autogen.sh` followed by `make` inorder to build the library.

When I type `./autogen.sh` in the msys terminal I get the following output:

```
checking for autoconf... 
checking for automake 1.11 or later... no
checking for aclocal 1.11 or later... no

You must have automake installed to compile vorbis.
Download the appropriate package for your distribution,
or get the source tarball at ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/
```

I have tried installing this http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/automake.htm but I still get the same error.

Any help that can get this library to work and link on windows will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the MSYS version of automake. You can install it with `mingw-get install msys-automake` or you can download it directly:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/msysdev/automake/